# Outlook Search does not show recent emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I am using Office Version 2206 (Build 15330.20230), the current version. When I am searching for an email it shows a message that maybe not all results are shown and that it is still indexing 127279 emails, many more emails than I have recieved since the issue occured. When I search for something it only shows results that more than a year old.

This problem occurs only since a couple of days, possibly since the last update from July 06.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure Windows Indexing includes Outlook and is complete.

See this screen shot for indexing options.  See that Outlook has been included.

Then go to Advanced Options, rebuild the index and let the rebuild complete. You said in your question that indexing had not completed.

Then open Outlook, search and use All Mailboxes.

This works on my Outlook systems.

[image: Index Settings]

Comment: Now it does not show any results (which is a good thing, because it shows that the index got deleted). However it stays at 0 items and stops after some time. The troubleshooting assistant says that that there is a wrong authorization for windows search directories and that it can't resolve that issue. Where can I change these?

Comment: I changed the secutiry property of the folder ProgramData/Microsoft/Search for everyone to "full access". The issue persists.

Comment: Open Task Manager, go to Services and scroll down for WSEARCH.  Make sure this is started.  At this point, this is not an Outlook issue; rather it is a Windows Search issue. Outlook seems to be reporting properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the mode you are running, try switching between Exchange Online mode and Cached mode to see if there would be any improvement:

[image]

[image]
[image]

You can also test by searching in OWA and see if the proper results can be returned.
If there is no issue in OWA, it's suggested to test  by [rebuilding the search catalog](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fix-search-issues-by-rebuildling-your-instant-search-catalog-213a2728-0ef4-427a-9bb2-aed329a59b17) and see how it goes.